# How to force the @property setter work only once?

Tags: python, oop

I have a class with a property (`signature` in the toy example below).
Some validation must be done, therefore there is a setter (`@signature.setter`).

```
class Signature:
    def __init__(self, input_array):
        self.signature = input_array

    @property
    def signature(self):
        return self._signature

    @signature.setter
    def signature(self, input_array):
        arr = np.array(input_array)
        if arr.ndim > 1:
            raise ValueError("Only one-dimensional arrays are accepted!")
        arr = np.unique(arr)
        if any(arr <= 0):
            raise ValueError("Only positive numbers are accepted!")
        self._signature = arr
```

```
lst = [2,3,4]
s = Signature(lst)
s.signature
# array([2, 3, 4])
```

But then I can write:

```
s.signature = [4, 5, 6]
```

and everything will work just fine because there is a `@signature.setter`.

Now what I want is to protect `s.signature` from being set after this concrete object is created.

Should I use @property inside `__new__`? How can I do this?

(I'm aware of [How to restrict setting an attribute outside of constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10929004/how-to-restrict-setting-an-attribute-outside-of-constructor) discussion, but there is no setter there...)

Comment: Rather than using a setter, why not remove the setter and only set _signature during the __init__? Other wise you could do a `if not self._signature` in the setter to only change _signature if it hasn't already been defined

Comment: If you expect to set ``self.signature`` only via ``__init__``, why have a public setter in the first place?

Comment: Well... This is so obvious. Now I can hardly understand why it was a problem for me. Sorry for bothering you, guys...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make the setter raise an exception if one tries to set `signature`. Just use a different method to check the value passed to `__init__` and set it:

```
import numpy as np
​
class Signature:
    def __init__(self, input_array):
        self._check_and_set_signature(input_array)
​
    @property
    def signature(self):
        return self._signature
​
    @signature.setter
    def signature(self, value):
        raise ValueError("signature already set")
        
        
        
    def _check_and_set_signature(self, input_array):
        arr = np.array(input_array)
        if arr.ndim > 1:
            raise ValueError("Only one-dimensional arrays are accepted!")
        arr = np.unique(arr)
        if any(arr <= 0):
            raise ValueError("Only positive numbers are accepted!")
        self._signature = arr
```

Sample run:

```
lst = [2,3,4]
s = Signature(lst)
print(s.signature)
# array([2, 3, 4])
​
s.signature = [4, 5, 6]
[2 3 4]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-68b91a667238> in <module>
     30 # array([2, 3, 4])
     31 
---> 32 s.signature = [4, 5, 6]

<ipython-input-6-68b91a667238> in signature(self, value)
     11     @signature.setter
     12     def signature(self, value):
---> 13         raise ValueError("signature already set")
     14 
     15 

ValueError: signature already set
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a rather old question, anyway I was thinking about this today and I came out with this solution which doesn't require additional methods but simply some private auxiliary object attributes.

```py
class Signature:
    def __init__(self, input_array):
        # auxiliary attributes
        self.__signature_set = False

        # actual __init__
        self.signature = input_array

    @property
    def signature(self):
        return self._signature

    @signature.setter
    def signature(self, input_array):
        if self.__signature_set == False:
            arr = np.array(input_array)
            if arr.ndim > 1:
                raise ValueError("Only one-dimensional arrays are accepted!")
            arr = np.unique(arr)
            if any(arr <= 0):
                raise ValueError("Only positive numbers are accepted!")
            self.__signature = arr
            self.__signature_set = True
        else:
            raise ValueError("signature already set!")
```

This way the setter acts as a setter and not just as a print function

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do mine. You need to check if the hidden(private) attribute already exists. Works fine

```
class Signature:
    def __init__(self, input_array):
        self.signature = input_array

    @property
    def signature(self):
        return self.__signature

    @signature.setter
    def signature(self, input_array):
        try:
            raise AssertionError(f"signature already set to object at {id(self.__signature)}")
        except AttributeError:
            pass
        
        arr = np.array(input_array)
        if arr.ndim > 1:
            raise ValueError("Only one-dimensional arrays are accepted!")
        arr = np.unique(arr)
        if any(arr <= 0):
            raise ValueError("Only positive numbers are accepted!")
        self.__signature = arr
```